# Getting data back from a mustache template Moodle 3.7

Tags: javascript, php, templates, moodle, mustache

I am doing some development in moodle 3.7 for a new admin tool plugin.  In this plugin I am generating a page from a custom made .mustache template.  This template contains a number of values that are defined and managed within it, that I want to access within my .php file once a submit button is pressed.

Currently however I am unable to access these submitted values that are defined within the template.  I can see their values in debugging under $form->_form->_submitValues but I cannot get to them due to _form being a protected variable of $form.  I called $form->get_data(), but that only gave me access to the elements that I defined in php as non html elements (hidden for example), not in the template.  I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but if anyone has any help they could give me on a path forward it would be much appreciated.

I am adding the template to the page using the function:

```
$mform->addElement(
    'html', 
    $OUTPUT->render_from_template(PLUGIN_TOOL_NAME/members', $rendercontext)
);
```

Please let me know any other information you may need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any variables that you want to have access to must be defined in the mform using these functions:

```
$mform->addElement('hidden', 'VARIABLE_NAME');
$mform->setType('VARIABLE_NAME', PARAM_INT);
```

Any JavaScript that needs to update these values must be in a separate .js file, not in your template. If the JavaScript works in your mustache file, it will still do exactly the same thing if you put it in a different .js file, as long as that .js file is included on the page.

One thing to note: if you use the functions I defined above, the variable will not have an ID.  instead it will have a name equal to whatever you put as VARIABLE_NAME.  This means however that you cannot use `document.getElementByID()` to get the instance of your variable.  instead you will have to use `document.getElementsByName("VARIABLE_NAME")[0]` to get access to your element.

If both of these things are done than you should see the value update and be sent to your mform on submit within the $data variable.